# how to center section in weblayout for mobile?

Tags: css, layout

I have a problem with section 'descr'.
When I open PC window, all content positions in center.
When I open mobile format, first section 'container' is ok (in center), but 'descr'
on the left side.
Why it could be?
'main' - is flex, and justify-content:center.
Also I added width:100% for 'main', but nothing changes

[image]

Comment: Have you set the meta (for viewport) in the head? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> Also why is the width: 100% scored through? I think we need you to provide a boiled-down example of a complete runnable snippet please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

When flex-direction: column, justify content and align items are changing directions. So, **you must use align-items: center;** to set them on the center, because flex-direction is set to column.

Comment: [nothing changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj8kQ.jpg)

Comment: Well, it's hard to comment before seeing your CSS in body either. You can try to make;

body{
  width: 100vw;
}

Comment: Without changes :( [](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8xTe.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must add `align-items: center` not `justify-content: center`, because when you add `flex-direction` to `column` you reverse things.

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: [nothing changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj8kQ.jpg)

Comment: Without changes :( [](i.stack.imgur.com/M8xTe.png)

Comment: @SpartakBorisov Send your code using codepen or jsfiddle or anything, so I can understand it.

Comment: https://codepen.io/spartachesko/pen/ZErQBXX

Answer (score 0):

The main axis is defined by flex-direction, which has four possible values:

- row
- row-reverse
- column
- column-reverse

Should you choose row or row-reverse, your main axis will run along the row in the inline direction.

If flex-direction is set to row the main axis runs along the row in the inline direction.
Choose column or column-reverse and your main axis will run from the top of the page to the bottom — in the block direction.

If flex-direction is set to column the main axis runs in the block direction.

Therefore, by using `flex-direction: column;` you are saying that your main axis is the vertical axis. This means that `justify-content: center;` will align your items vertically, not horizontally. So, to align them horizontally, you must use `align-items: center;` to align the items along the cross axis.

Comment: [nothing changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj8kQ.jpg)

Comment: In that picture it seems that you are still using ``justify-content: center;`` instead of: ``align-items: center;``.

Comment: Sorry, this is last screen [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7F69.png)

Comment: Could you send maybe a codepen or jsfiddle link to your code so I can have a play around with it, otherwise, there isn't much else I can help you with.

Comment: https://codepen.io/spartachesko/pen/ZErQBXX

Comment: After some testing, I have concluded that the reason your ``.descr`` box isn't centered is that something is causing your website to crop which typically overwrites and messes with the styles used to center boxes. I suggest you look through your code and make sure that things are not being given fixed widths that contradict the width of the screen. Other than that, there is not much more that I can advise, sorry!